# error Platform.getBundle("").start();

Tags: macos, eclipse-rcp, osgi, bundle, 32bit-64bit

Im using RCP and I have this 'start' method in my Application class:

```
public class Application implements IApplication {
public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
    Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();

    try {
        // Enforcing that Spring Dynamic Modules extender is started
        Platform.getBundle("org.springframework.osgi.extender").start();  **//THIS IS LINE 26**
        int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());
        if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART)
            return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
        else
            return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
    } finally {
        display.dispose();
    }

}
//More methods...
}
```

And the error says:

```
!SESSION 2012-01-27 21:59:11.417 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=es_ES
Framework arguments:  -product com.blackthorne.mvctest.product -d32
Command-line arguments:  -product com.blackthorne.mvctest.product -data /Users/Hepale/Documents/Java/Wisconsin - ET/Eclipse/MVCTest/../runtime-com.blackthorne.mvctest.product -dev file:/Users/Hepale/Documents/Java/Wisconsin - ET/Eclipse/MVCTest/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/com.blackthorne.mvctest.product/dev.properties -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -consoleLog -d32

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-01-27 21:59:12.168
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.blackthorne.mvctest.Application.start(Application.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
An error has occurred.
```

I believe it's cos java version, but I added '-d32' to a Program argument (in Run Configurations...)
I dont know what is missing.

Any one who can help me, I do appreciate, cos it's really an emergency.

I know in this world of programmers, we need to share our doubts and knowledge.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the start-level of OSGi bundle to ensure the bundle is properly started. You can set the start-level via the Product Configuration on the "Configuration" page or directly in the `config.ini` file via the `osgi.bundles` property.